# Spritekit drastic frame rate drop

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, frame-rate, skphysicsbody

I have tried my best to boil this question down as simple as possible. I have a coin object in  my game:

```
@implementation
-(CollectableCoin*)initWithLocation:(CGPoint) Location andValue: (int) val
{
self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"coin"];
[self setScale:.35];
_value = val;
_collected = false;

self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = APAColliderTypeCoin;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = APAColliderTypeBall;
self.physicsBody.mass = 0.00009;
self.physicsBody.restitution = .35;
self.position = Location;
self.name = @"collectableCoin";
return self;
}
@end
```

I also have a shelf object:

```
@implementation Shelf

-(Shelf*)initWithLocation:(CGPoint) location andWidth:(NSInteger) width
{
self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"shelf"];
if(self)
{
    self.size = CGSizeMake(width, HEIGHT);

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = false;
    self.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    self.position = location;
    self.name = @"shelf";

    SKSpriteNode* topOfShelf;

    if(width > 5)
        topOfShelf = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(width-2, 1)];
    else
        topOfShelf = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(width, 1)];

    topOfShelf.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:topOfShelf.size];
    topOfShelf.physicsBody.restitution = 1;
    topOfShelf.physicsBody.dynamic = false;
    topOfShelf.position = CGPointMake(0, location.y + self.size.height/2);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.y + self.size.height/2]);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.y]);
    topOfShelf.name = @"shelf";

    [self addChild:topOfShelf];
}
return self;
}

@end
```

I create a scene like so:

```
-(id)initWithSizeTest:(CGSize)size
{

self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
_gameState = READYTOSTART;
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
{
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        CollectableCoin* orb = [[CollectableCoin alloc] initWithLocation:CGPointMake(i*10, self.size.height*.75) andValue:1];
        [self addChild:orb];
    }

    Shelf* shelf = [[Shelf alloc] initWithLocation:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2) andWidth:self.size.width];
    [self addChild:shelf];
}
return self;
```

}

Here is the touchesBegan method:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */
if(_gameState == READYTOSTART)
{
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -2.0);
    _gameState = PLAYING;
    [[self childNodeWithName:@"taptostart"] removeFromParent];
}
```

When the scene starts, I have a row of coins hovering above a shelf, gravity is disabled, and I have a solid 60fps. When I tap the screen, the touchesbegan function enables gravity and the coins fall on the shelf, and the frame rate drops to 5fps. The didBeginContact function is not being called because the shelf object is not dynamic nor does it have contact or collision bitmasks, so I am fairly sure that it is not being overloaded by extraneous calls to didBeginContact. This happens on an iPad mini and an iPhone 4s, but not in any of the simulators. This is a very simple example of the actual problem that I am having. Anyone have any insights?

Comment: Are the coins in constant contact with each other? Are they maybe stuck inside each other, or constantly contacting with the world boundaries (if any)?

Comment: What happens if you set the restitution to 0.2 (or just not set the restitution), on all things.

Please post the touchesbegan method :)

Comment: I do not believe the coins are in constant contact with each other. With sprite kit, its terribly difficult to see the physics body. Even when I make the physics body 10% the size of the image the node contains, it still behaves the same. Changing the restitution does nothing, as does not setting it at all. The FPS still drop to unbearably low levels. Been up all night trying to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the number of coins to see at what point your FPS starts dropping?

Comment: Does your app use more than one UIViewController? This may sound completely unrelated, but I was pulling my hair out for a few days before coming to [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9203) because I was experiencing really bad performance. After refactoring to use a single UIViewController all my troubles went away.

Comment: I have tried decreasing the number of coins. Thats not really the point though because before the coins come into contact with the shelf, the simulation is running at optimum speed. Only when the coins come into contact with this shelf does the frame rate drop. I am only using one view controller. This is really just the weirdest damn thing I have ever dealt with. I may just have to go with sangony and limit the number of coins that are present on the screen, this will really limit the game play though :(

Comment: So in the larger scheme of things, I think the p